# Client side validation not working on password

Tags: asp.net-mvc, identity, unobtrusive-validation

I Have the following register view

```
@model YFA.Models.RegisterViewModel
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Register";
}

<h2 class="col-md-offset-1">@ViewBag.Title</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-1">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BranchId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.BranchId, new SelectList(Model.Branches, "BranchId", "BranchName", 0), "Please Select", new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BranchId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<h3 class="col-md-offset-1">Name</h3>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3  col-md-offset-1">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "John" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Smith" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<h3 class="col-md-offset-1">Contact Details</h3>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-1">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Mobile, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Mobile, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "07724 567890" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Mobile, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-1">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "me@provider.com" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ConfirmEmail, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ConfirmEmail, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "me@provider.com" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ConfirmEmail, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <h3 class="col-md-offset-1">Dates</h3>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-1">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DateOfBirth, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DateOfBirth, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "01/12/80" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DateOfBirth, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Joined, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Joined, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "01/12/10" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Joined, "", new {   @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <h3 class="col-md-offset-1">Password</h3>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-1">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ConfirmPassword, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ConfirmPassword, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ConfirmPassword, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger"     })
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-10">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Register" />
                </div>
            </div>

}

@section Scripts {
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#DateOfBirth").datepicker({
            format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
            startDate: "-120y",
            endDate: "-10y",
            startView: 2,
            calendarWeeks: true,
            defaultViewDate: { year: 1975, month: 01, day: 01 }
        });
    });

    $(function () {
        $("#Joined").datepicker({
            format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
            startDate: "-20y",
            endDate: "1y",
            startView: 2,
            calendarWeeks: true,
            defaultViewDate: { year: 2010, month: 01, day: 01 }
        });
    });
</script>

}
```

The client side validation works fine for every field except the password field. it will warn if the password isn't the correct length but won't warn about the need for a capital or non alpha numeric character.

I'm using asp.net mvc identity.

The view model section for password is:

```
        [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }
```

And the post controller is:

```
        //
    // POST: /Account/Register
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                var now = DateTime.Now;
                UserManager.AddClaim(user.Id, new Claim(ClaimTypes.GivenName, model.FirstName));
                //Add the new club details to the database
                var Instructor = new Instructor
                {
                    FirstName = model.FirstName,
                    LastName = model.LastName,
                    Joined = model.Joined,
                    Email = model.Email,
                    Mobile = model.Mobile,
                    BranchId = model.BranchId,
                    LGVDrv = model.LGVDrv,
                    MiniBusDrv = model.MiniBusDrv,
                    Operational = model.Operational,
                    ApplicationUserId = user.Id,      
                };
                db.Instructors.Add(Instructor);
                db.SaveChanges();
                var currentUser = UserManager.FindByName(user.UserName);
                await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false, rememberBrowser: false);
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            else
            {
                AddErrors(result);
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

When posting the form it returns the view because var result fair to succeed.

Comment: did you try adding [RegularExpression] validator for the model? There you can specify your regex rules to check for your password

Comment: Thanks thats sorted it

Comment: Please post the solution as an answer so it can be "accepted".  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the comment above I amended the viewModel by adding a regular expression to it as follows:

```
        [Required]
    [RegularExpression(@"^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z].*[a-z].*[a-z]).{8,20}$",
                    ErrorMessage = "Password is not valid, it must be between 8 - 20 characters and contain a number and a capital letter")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }
```